# iOS | Tapping on Marker Zooms out Google Map SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, swift4

I have a `GMSMapView` instance, `orderMapView`, which is linked to my `UIViewController`. I give Location Permissions and later make self as delegate of `orderMapView`

```
orderMapView.delegate = self
```

I also make the class conform to `GMSMapViewDelegate`. I then initiate multiple markers in `viewDidLoad`, one of which is like this:

```
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(dataLat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(dataLng))
marker.title = dataName
marker.snippet = "LAT: \(dataLat), LONG: \(dataLng)"
marker.appearAnimation = .pop
marker.map = orderMapView
marker.isDraggable = true
marker.isTappable = true
```

I also implement the following delegate methods:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
//1 - IT NEITHER COMES HERE
    print(coordinate)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    print(position)
}


func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
//2 - IT NEITHER COMES HERE
    orderMapView.selectedMarker = marker
    return true
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 70))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 6

    let lbl1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 8, y: 8, width: view.frame.size.width - 16, height: 15))
    lbl1.text = marker.title
    view.addSubview(lbl1)

    let lbl2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: lbl1.frame.origin.x, y: lbl1.frame.origin.y + lbl1.frame.size.height + 3, width: view.frame.size.width - 16, height: 15))
    lbl2.text = marker.snippet
    lbl2.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .light)
    view.addSubview(lbl2)

    return view
}
```

I can see the markers on the map but when I tap it, the map zooms out and never shows the info windows on those markers. Please help.

**UPDATE:** This is happening on Simulator as I don't have a device. Can that be the sore and sole problem?